# Expected type 'object'. Found 'void'.intelephense(1006)

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, laravel-livewire, intelephense

Laravel v 9.11

Livewire v 2.5

vscode v 1.67.2

intelephense v 1.8.2

In laravel project i have a livewire component with a search function

**model Department:**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Department extends Model
{
  public static function search($search)
  {
    return empty($search)
      ? static::query()
      : static::query()
      ->where('department_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
  }
}
```

**livewire: DepartmentWire**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin\Departments;

use App\Models\Department;

class DepartmentWire extends Component
{

  public $search = '';

  public function read()
  {
    $data = [
      'departments' => Department::search($this->search) //--> error here
        ->with('users')
        ->withCount('users')
        ->orderBy('department_name')
        ->paginate(10),
    ];
    return $data;
  }


  public function render()
  {
    return view('livewire.admin.departments.department-wire', $this->read());
  }
}
```

every thing works fine except that `intelephense` gives me an error

`Expected type 'object'. Found 'void'.intelephense(1006)`

Comment: You should create a scope  instead https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: This is also just a editor thing, has nothing to do with Laravel or Livewire directly

Comment: How to use scope in my case !? .. i tried but it gives me error ....  Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

Comment: There's examples in the docs I linked https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#dynamic-scopes

Answer (score 1):

problem solved when downgrade `intelephense` to version 1.3.11